# Set status of a record with group by multiple rows in SAS

Tags: sas

I've a table with two columns

```
create table incident 
(
  incident_name VARCHAR(256),
  APPStatus VARCHAR(20)
);
```

this table has data as

```
incident_name  |  APPStatus 
  first        |  In progress
  first        |  In progress
  first        |  done
  second       |  done
  second       |  overdue
```

I want to set status of incident  based on the APPStatus column as, if atleast one APPStatus is in progress incident_status is "in progeress"

or if  one is overdue incident_status is overdue

I've tried

```
proc sql;
create table inc_status as
select incident_name, APPStatus,
incstatus = case when APSTATUS="In Progress" then "In Progress"
                 when APSTATUS="done" then "done"
                 else APSTATUS
            end
from incident 
group by incident_name ;
quit;

data  inc_status;
set incident ;
if APSTATUS="In Progress"
    then incstatus = "In Progress";
by incident_name ;
run;
```

but it's not resulting incident status as group by of incident_name

**Expected Result**

```
incident_name  |  APPStatus      |  incstatus 
  first        |  In progress    |  In Progress
  first        |  In progress    |  In Progress
  first        |  done           |  In Progress
  second       |  done           |  overdue
  second       |  overdue        |  overdue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an existential correlated subquery in a `case` when-expression to determine which value to assign to the grouped items.

```
proc sql;
create table have
(
  incident_name VARCHAR(256),
  APPStatus VARCHAR(20)
);

insert into have
values ("first","In progress")
values ("first","In progress")
values ("first","done")
values ("second","done")
values ("second","overdue")
values ("third","done")
values ("third","welldone")
values ("fourth","In progress")
values ("fourth","overdue")
values ("fourth","done")
;


* case statement with existential correlated sub-queries;

create table want as
select 
  incident_name,
  appstatus,
  case 
    when exists (
      select * from have as inner 
      where inner.incident_name=outer.incident_name 
        and APPStatus="In progress"
    ) then "In Progress"
    when exists (
      select * from have as inner 
      where inner.incident_name=outer.incident_name 
        and APPStatus="overdue"
    ) then "overdue"
    else 
      " "
  end as incstatus
from have as outer
;
```

Another approach is to using mapping data (instead of hardcoding the existential lookups in when subqueries).  Left join the data to an aggregating sub-query, of same, that selects the group-wide mapping to apply.

```
create table map
(
  APPStatus varchar(20),
  IncStatus varchar(20),
  priority int
);

insert into map
values ("In progress", "In Progress", 1)
values ("overdue", "overdue", 2)
;

create table want2 as
select 
  left.incident_name,
  left.APPStatus,
  right.IncStatus
from 
  have as left
left join 
  ( 
    select  distinct
      have.incident_name,
      map.IncStatus, 
      map.priority
    from
      have
    join 
      map
    on 
      have.APPStatus = map.APPStatus
    group by
      incident_name
    having
      priority=min(priority)
  ) as right
on
  left.incident_name = right.incident_name
;
```

A DATA step with DOW processing can compute the group-wide value to apply to each item in the group.  How the computation is made is dependent on the expected conditions of the status values in each incident group.  If the group-wide value to apply has only one distinct possibility in the group then the logic is simpler.  A more complex computation would account for multiple possibilities and chose the one with the highest priority:

```
data want3;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.incident_name);
    set have;
    length IncStatus $20;
    by incident_name notsorted;

    * this select only works 100% if APPStatus that occur in a group are never multiple possible mappings;

    select (APPStatus);
      when ("In progress") IncStatus = "In Progress";
      when ("overdue") IncStatus = "overdue";
      otherwise IncStatus = IncStatus;
    end;
  end;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    OUTPUT;
  end;
run;

data want4;
  * order of values listed is priority;
  array _source(2) $20 _temporary_ ("In progress", "overdue");
  array _target(2) $20 _temporary_ ("In Progress", "overdue");


  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.incident_name);
    set have;
    length IncStatus $20;
    by incident_name notsorted;

    * _index is the priority aspect of the group-wide computation;
    * Negative is used because variable initializations done at
    * top of step by implicit loop will set _gwindex to missing.
    * Thus any first found _index (as negated) will be > _gwindex
    * (being missing per reset at top of step);
    * Also -1 > -2 so priority established by value order
    * in mapping arrays is maintained;

    _index = -whichc(AppStatus, of _source(*));
    if (_index) and (_index > _gwindex) then do; * gw ~ group-wide;
      _gwindex = _index;
      IncStatus = _target(-_index);
    end;
  end;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    OUTPUT;
  end;

  drop _index _gwindex;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

your logic was close for sql. this is for either you have status = in progress or over due

```
  proc sql;
    create table inc_status as
      select incident_name, appstatus,
               max(case when APPStatus="In progress" then "In progress"
             when APPStatus="overdue" then "overdue"
             else " "
        end) as inc
     from incident 
    group by incident_name;
   quit;
```

[image]